# Is this intended order of operations for this Django template tag conditional correct?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, conditional-statements

In basic terms, this is the what I am looking for

```
{% if not A or (B and C == D) %}
```

In a Django template tag (unable to use parentheses), is this the same result?

```
{% if not A or B and C == D %}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would suggest to create another context variable to store `B and C == D` and use it here

Answer (score 0):

If i were u i would do it inside views.py

```py
def your_view(request):
    # your codes
    condition = A or (B and C == D)

    context = {'condition': condition}
    return render(request, "your_template.html", context)
```

then in your_template.html

```html
{% if not condition %}
 .
 .
{% endif %}
```